# Получить блок со стороннего сайта, зная удаленный class/id блока

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Необходимо загрузить **конкретную часть/блок/элемент** со стороннего сайта.
*Сайт*: https://www.kia.ru/models/rio/desc/
*Элемент, который необходимо загрузить*: **div.car-info** (это блок конструктора)

По возможности использовать JS.

Моя идея заключалась в том, чтобы получить сайт в iframe. Найти в нем класс car-info, считать положение и размеры. Перерисовать iframe в соответствии с положением и размерами.

Данный код выдает ошибку

*Pug*:

```
iframe(src="https://www.kia.ru/models/rio/desc/", frameborder="0" width="100%" height="200px")#constructor
```

*jQuery*:

```
$('#constructor').load(function() {
    var car =  $('#constructor').contents()
    car.find('.car-info');
});
```

Возможно у кого-то есть предложения?

Comment: Я не уверен, что у Вас это выйдет с помощью iframe.

Comment: Не уверен, что это вообще возможно....

Comment: а если спарсить сайт?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, пришлось закостылить. Пока что на чистом html+css без JS.

```
.row#hidden
    iframe#constructor(allowfullscreen scrolling="no" src="https://www.kia.ru/models/rio/desc/")

#hidden
{
    overflow: hidden
    position: relative
    width: 100%
    height: 500px
}

#constructor
{
    position: absolute
    top: -200px
    width: 100%
    height: 600px
    overflow: hidden
    border: none
    margin-left: 18px
}
```

Теперь вопрос со ссылками. Как заменить им пути и атрибуты.